# Updating MySQL table at once or on every click

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a calendar created with a table. Users can mark the dates on the calendar by clicking on it. I wonder is it safe or good to update mySQL fields on every click or to update fields on one Submit button. 
I created a very simple on click update with jquery, but I wonder what the better way is.

Comment: Is the calendar shared between all users, or do they all have their own instance of it with their own marked dates?

Comment: I would be concerned about inadvertent updates -- the user didn't realize that they had clicked on a date (they could have scrolled to a different month?) or they changed their mind. For usability, I think you're better off having the user say "Yes, I want to save this" by clicking on a button.

Comment: You might also want to post your question -- the behavior part, not the database details -- on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What kind of *safety* are you concerned about?  How shared is the data between views or users of the calendar?

Comment: yes calendar is shared between users who will update their calendar, but they haw they unique ID of their product/calendar, and lets say i expect to be around 5000 products but 1000 users maybe more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. MySQL is more than capable enough to handle the requests your likely are going to throw at it until there are more than hundreds of updates to the same table at the same time.

It is a little more user-friendly to immediately save the changes trough AJAX than to have a submit though, so I'd go with the latter.